# In-place inverse of DFT?

Tags: fourier-analysis, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to understand (by implementing) the Cooley Tukey algorithm for an array $[x_0, \dotsc, x_{2^N-1}]$ of *real valued* data.  Since the input data is real valued, the spectrum will have conjugate symmetry: $\hat{x}_{2^N-k} = \hat{x}_k^{\ast}$. Therefore it suffices to only store the first $2^{N-1}+1$ terms and moreover $\hat{x}_0$ and $\hat{x}_{2^{N-1}}$ are real numbers.  The Cooley Tukey algorithm can be adapted in such a way that it does not need more space than that to compute a dft.  The steps are:

1. Reorder input data
2. Combine data recursively

However, I don't see how the *inverse* dft can be done in a similar manner.  That is, given the first half of a conjugate symmetric spectrum, is there a way to recover the original real data that does not need additional space?

I have the nagging feeling that I'm missing something quite obvious.  However, I did also not find any reference for it.  Any pointers appreciated!

**Edit:** The procedure indicated by Joriki works.  However, the process of in-place reordering as the final step turns out to be a bit tedious to do fast.  I now found an answer to my own question:  It is possible to do an inverse transform by first reordering the data and then applying a recursion.  Here's how.

Let $n = 2^N$ be the input size for the forward transform (on a sequence of $n$ real numbers) and $\zeta_n = e^{2\pi i/n}$. Let $S$ be the inverse DFT defined on half of a symmetric spectrum
$$
S(x_0, z_1, \dots, z_{n/2-1}, x_{n/2}; m)
$$
where $x$ indicates a real number and $z$ a complex number and $m$ the argument. Let $F$ be the usual inverse DFT on a full complex spectrum.  Then the central identity for the recursion is:

$$
S(x_0, z_1, \dots, z_{n/2-1}, x_{n/2};m) = S(x_0, z_2, \dotsc, z_{n/2-2}, x_{n/2}; m) + 2\mathrm{Re}\left(\zeta_n^m F(z_1, z_5, \dotsc, \overline{z_7}, \overline{z_3}; m)\right).
$$

The first summand uses all entries with an even index, the second term those with an odd index, rearranged and conjugated in a certain way.  (First put $z_1$ in front, then $z_3$ conjugated at the back, $z_5$ at the front, $z_7$ conjugated at the back, and so on.)  Now both summands can be computed in-place: $F$ with the usual Cooley-Tukey procedure and $S$ by recursion.

Comment: "... and $\hat{x}_0$ and $\hat{x}_{2N−1}$ are real numbers." How come? You store half the numbers, but the numbers are complex, so you have not attained any form of compression.

Comment: @RodCarvalho: no indeed, the size is the same.  Only for the full complex valued spectrum it would be twice as much.  Anyway, the real point is an in-place procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each part of step 2, you're applying a transformation of the form

$$
\pmatrix{x_k\\x_{k+d}}\to\pmatrix{1&\omega\\1&-\omega}\pmatrix{x_k\\x_{k+d}}\;.
$$

The inverse transformation is

$$
\pmatrix{x_k\\x_{k+d}}\to\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\\overline\omega&-\overline\omega}\pmatrix{x_k\\x_{k+d}}\;.
$$

So you can just perform all the inverse operations in reverse order, and then undo the reordering. Of course you need to take into account the optimizations you made for real-valued data; but since mathematically all the operations are invertible, you can always apply the inverse operation to your optimized representation.

Comment: Yes, it was kinda obvious.  :-)  (By the way, the transformation is on four data points to nicely handle the restricted spectrum.) To do the reordering in the end is a minor drawback, but better than nothing.  I'll just wait a little longer to see if a "forward" approach comes up.  If not, I'll accept your answer.